# How to replace inline event handlers to event listeners in slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I was wondering if someone could point me in right direction for how to replace inline event handlers to event listeners.
I have a slideshow with an picture gallery below and whenever a user clicks next/previous button or a mini-picture in the gallery a function is called with a value i.e.:`onclick="exfunction(-1)`.
I am totally new to javascript and not sure how to pass a value through an event listener. Any thoughts would be much appriciated.

Here is some of my code :

```
 <div class="slides gallery">
      <img src="image">
  </div>

  <div class="slides gallery">
      <img src="image"> 
  </div>


 <button class="prev2" onClick="plusSlides(-1)"> &#10094;</button>
 <button class="next2" onClick="plusSlides(1)"> &#10095;</button>

 <div class="row-pic">
      <img class="mini-pic" src="image" width="100" onclick="currentSlide(5)">
 </div>
    
 <div class="row-pic">
      <img class="mini-pic" src="image" onclick="currentSlide(6)" >
</div>


JS

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its more secure when you use event listener, Because your currently functions is declared as global function and it can be called by console.log or the other way.

Check how to convert to event listener below.

```
<div class="slides gallery">
      <img src="image">
  </div>

  <div class="slides gallery">
      <img src="image"> 
  </div>


 <button class="prev2"> &#10094;</button>
 <button class="next2"> &#10095;</button>

 <div class="row-pic">
      <img class="mini-pic" src="image" width="100" value="5">
 </div>
    
 <div class="row-pic">
      <img class="mini-pic" src="image" value="6">
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var slideIndex = 1;
    $('.prev2').click(function(){
        showSlides(slideIndex -= 1);
    })

    $('.next2').click(function(){ 
        showSlides(slideIndex += 1);
    })

    $(".mini-pic").click(function(){
        showSlides(this.value);
    });

    function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }
});
</script>
```

As you can see if you want input some parameter like index of picture you can passed from value.